# how add photos in facebook album using php?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

How can I upload images in Facebook album using graph api in php?
Can anybody help me,

If anyone help me than I am appreciate with all your answers

Can anyone please give me demo if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the document in the following link :

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

This should help you

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/   link not found in that questions

Comment: @anandbhoraniya the rest api is deprecated. So please go through the link given in the post

Comment: i got error like "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: @anandbhoraniya please make sure that the url given in the facebook app settings matches the domain in which you are working. If it does not match then this error occurs